# Uniqueness of the solution to a discrete boundary value problem

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given a Markov chain with state space $\Omega$ and transition matrix $P$, and $A\subset \Omega$, define function$f(x)=\Bbb E _x(\tau_A)$, where $\tau_A$ is the "stopping time into set $A$", meaning the first time the Markov chain reaches a state in $A$.

It has been shown that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$, and $f\left( x \right) = 1 + \mathop \sum \limits_{y \in {\rm{\Omega }}} P\left( {x,y} \right)f\left( y \right)$ for $x\notin A$.

The question is to show $f$ is **uniquely determined**.

I have been puzzled by this problem for a while and have not get a clue. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

---

The following is part of the textbook that might be related to this problem, which shows the uniqueness of the stationary distribution.

> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: In your second sentence, you surely mean $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in A$, right?

Comment: @MarkFischler Yes. That is a typo. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I think I'd attack this by assuming there are two solutions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and then writing an equation for $h(x)\equiv f(x)-g(x)$ looking like $h(x) = \sum P(x,y)h(y)$.  If you can show that $h(x)$ is zero...

Comment: @MarkFischler Thank you for your hint. I have solved the problem!

Comment: @Tony Could you post your solution? It may help future readers of this question.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I posted the answer. Currently it is in picture because I don't have to type in Latex at this moment. I will try to refine it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in image. I will find some time to type in latex later.

> [image]

The solution uses the result of a previous problem.

> [image]